# Question regarding rendering fields in node.tpl.php

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I'm confused in how the fields can be rendered.
There are 2 variables in node.tpl.php `$node` and `$content`, both of which contain fields.
My task was to render all fields separately, to surround them with custom html. First I've tried

```
print render($content['field_service_summary'])
```

and got

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["#markup"]=> string(11) "Engineering" } } Engineering
```

in result.

Trying to get rid of that array, I've taken another approach so the code became:

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_service_summary'); 
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_service_summary', $field[0]);
print render($output);
```

which actually worked, so, to clear this out I have following questions:

1) Where did that array come from when doing `print render(content['field_service_engineering']);` and how can I get rid of it(I still like this rendering approach better cause it's just shorter) ?

2) Is the second method I've used totally good, with no drawbacks ?

3) What's the point in keeping fields info both in `$content` and `$node` especially regarding that in vanilla node.tpl.php only `$content` is used for rendering fields ?

4) Just my curiosity: in `$content` array every field has value #object which seems to contain the node object itself. What is it for ?

Answer (score 1):

1. That should be `print render($content['field_service_summary']);` (notice the `$` sign prefixing the variable name).
2. It's technically OK, but unless you've customised the preprocess workflow to a large degree, what you'll find at `$content['field_service_summary']` is actually the result of a call to `field_view_value()` anyway, so you're just duplicating logic. If you find that method to be the way forward for whatever reason, at least move it into a preprocess function so it's not cluttering up the template file.
3. When nodes are loaded, they get field data attached to them. That data is in a certain format. When a field is viewed (e.g. with `field_view_field()`) that data is restructured into a render array, suitable to be run through `render()`/`drupal_render()`. The arrays might well contain the same data in some places, but they're formatted differently for their various different purposes.
4. It's a reference to the node object. It might be used by a theme/render function, or it might not. Core puts it there by convention. Remember it's just a *reference* to the object, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the '$' when writing question, it's all-right in code. Anyway, the problem seems that $content['field_service_summary'] is different from what field_view_value() returns, so the render function returns different results placing some array in the beginning of rendered value in case of render($content['field_service_summary']).

Comment: It seems, I've found where the bug is - in the end of every field render array there is a `[0] => Array
        (
            [#markup] => Page not found
        )` section. Trying to understand where did it come from.