# How to render a node field

Tags: 7, nodes, theming, entities

I can get the field using `entity_metadata_wrapper` like this

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node, array(
    'langcode' => $GLOBALS['language'],
    'bundle' => 'unit'
     )
);

$field_value = $node_wrapper->field_photo->value();
```

And that returns an array which I don't know how to render. I tried `drupal_render()` but it seems that it doesn't do the job.

So how can I render this field ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question regarding rendering fields in node.tpl.php](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74200/question-regarding-rendering-fields-in-node-tpl-php)

Comment: I tried that solution and it works, but what if I want to render the field returned by entity_metadata_wrapper()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The photo field is an image field? The value() function returns an array which is actual file data linked to the image. To render (or to create a renderable build), you can for example use `theme_image` function, which prints out an <img> tag.

```
$node = node_load(43);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node, array(
    'langcode' => $GLOBALS['language'],
    'bundle' => 'subject'
));

$field_value = $node_wrapper->field_teaser_image->value();
$build = array(
    '#theme' => 'image',
    '#path' => $field_value['uri'],
    '#alt' => $field_value['alt'],
    '#title' => $field_value['title'],
    '#width' => $field_value['width'],
    '#height' => $field_value['height'],
);

print drupal_render($build);
```

Comment: That works only for image fields. but I have other fields I want to render I just used that one as an example

Comment: Depending the type of field, the method for rendering is different ... (plain values, arrays, ...). Why don't you use `field_get_items` and `field_view_value` for the rendering?

Comment: I will only need this photo field for now after all, so I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: This shows a huge shortcoming of metadata_wrappers in my opinion. I would hope that we could just do `$node_wrapper->field_teaser_image->render();`